onNotificationReceivedInForeground from aws-amplify/push-notifications is not triggered in react-native app
What could be the reason for onNotificationReceivedInForeground from aws-amplify/push-notifications not being triggered by APNs sandbox message in react-native iOS app?
More details - github issue
When sending APNs sandbox message:

If app is in background, message will be received OK
If app is in foreground, nothing happens

